# Variable getting destroyed before calling lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, clang++, g++4.8

I'm trying to build a lambda that wraps some input functions with some pre/post actions.

- My code works fine and pre/post actions get called correctly if I try to wrap a regular function/lambda.
- However, when I try to apply my decorating lambda to a function that it produced before, my program crashes after complaining that the inner function was freed at some point (this is confirmed by valgrind).

What puzzles me is that the crash depends on the compiler: the code works perfectly fine with `Xcode 6 clang` (`clang-3.6` based), but crashes on linux using `clang++-3.6` and `g++4.8.4`.

I've made a small program that reproduces the behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

typedef function<void(void)> NestedFn;

int main()
{
    // Create a cfunction
    auto lambdaFactory = [&](string title, NestedFn nestedFunc)
    {
        // title is copied to the new lambda
        return [&, title]() {
            cerr << "------------ START -----------" << endl;
            cerr << "Inside: " << title << endl;
            nestedFunc();
            cerr << "------------- END ------------" << endl;
        };
    }

    auto l1 = lambdaFactory("1", []() { cerr << "\tNest (1)" << endl; });
    auto l2 = lambdaFactory("2", []() { cerr << "\tNest (2)" << endl; });

    l1(); // Works ok, displays, START, 1, END
    l2(); // Same here

    auto dobble = lambdaFactory("Dobble", l1);
    dobble(); // Display START, Inside Dobble, START, 
              // then crashes when trying to execute nestedFunc(), ie l1()
}
```

What did I get wrong in the variable scope management ? And is there any reason for this program **not** crashing using Apple's LLVM ?

**EDIT**

For the record, here is the correct `lambdaFactory` after the correction suggested by [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) :

```
auto lambdaFactory = [&](string title, NestedFn nestedFunc)
{
  return [&, title, nestedFunc]() {
        cerr << "------------ START -----------" << endl;
        cerr << "Inside: " << title << endl;
        nestedFunc();
        cerr << "------------- END ------------" << endl;
    };
};
```

Comment: The problem is that `lambdaFactory`'s arguments are passed by value, so you must capture them by value if the lambda is to be returned. Otherwise you have a dangling reference, since the function arguments go out of scope once it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda returned by a call to `lambdaFactory` captures `nestedFunc` by reference, but `nestedFunc` is a function argument passed by value, so it goes out of scope as soon as the call to `lambdaFactory` returns, resulting in a dangling reference.

> And is there any reason for this program not crashing using Apple's LLVM ?

Undefined behavior is undefined. You are also likely using two different standard library implementations (libc++ on Mac/libstdc++ on linux), so there are likely differences in how everything is laid out etc.

Comment: Thanks ! I've changed the line inside `lambdaFactory` from `return [&, title]() {` to `return [&, title, nestedFunc]() {` and it works. I didn't realize that `nestedFunc` was considered as a value inside the `lambdaFactory`.